# File upload security vulnerability

Tags: php, lamp

Is there any file upload security vulnerability in my code? I am using apache in my server side. File upload is enabled in php.ini file.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)//maximum upload size is 100 kb
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$var="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$samp=str_shuffle($var);
$pass=substr($samp,0,20);// creating a random text for file name.
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext=".{$ext}";
$newfilename="upload/".$pass.$ext;
rename("upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"],$newfilename );
    echo "Stored in: " . $newfilename;
echo "<br>extension : ".$ext;
  }
}
}
else
  echo "File size is too large..";
?>
```

Comment: Sounds more like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially, yes.

What would happen if someone uploaded a PHP file?  Would they be able to determine the filename, file URL, and run the PHP file?

If so, that program could use the scandir() function to get a list of all your filenames.

To prevent this, you could store the files outside DocumentRoot path, refuse to accept .php files, or use .htaccess to turn the PHP engine off in that directory.

Comment: Will do.. . Will check for extension of the file and make it store outside root directory. Can any intruder can exploit file size checking(if($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)) and upload large sized files? Am asking because, my main intension is to prevent uploading files not more than 100 KB.

Comment: I think you have what you are looking for on file size.Your file size checking will prevent a large file from being successful, yes.  They can *try* to post a file, and it will upload, but your script will refuse to accept the file and it will be thrown away automatically.